# I want to do logical masking on an image in Julia

Tags: julia

I want to do logical masking in Julia.
If 2nd and 3rd elements of an image equal, they should be changed to 0 and others be not changed.
I tried this;

```
mask = img[:, :, 2] .== img[:, :, 3]
img[:, :, 2][mask] .= 0
```

The image size is (1200, 1920, 3), but size of img[:, :, 2] is (1676348,).
I guess 'true' values on mask remain, but 'false' values are removed.
I want to deal the logical-masked-image as an image, therefore it should be (1200, 1920, 1).
How to keep the size with logical masking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to write what you're asking for might be `img[mask, 2] .= 0`, but this doesn't work on Julia up through 1.5. As a workaround, you can create a *mutable* slice with `@view`:

```
julia> img = cat([1 2; 3 4], [1 5; 6 7]; dims=3)
2×2×2 Array{Int64, 3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 1  2
 3  4

[:, :, 2] =
 1  5
 6  7

julia> mask = img[:,:,1] .== img[:,:,2]
2×2 BitMatrix:
 1  0
 0  0

julia> v = @view img[:,:,2]
2×2 view(::Array{Int64, 3}, :, :, 2) with eltype Int64:
 1  5
 6  7

julia> v[mask] .= 0
1-element view(reshape(view(::Array{Int64, 3}, :, :, 2), 4), [1]) with eltype Int64:
 0

julia> img
2×2×2 Array{Int64, 3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 1  2
 3  4

[:, :, 2] =
 0  5
 6  7
```

It's worth emphasizing that without the `@view`, `v = img[:,:,2]` would create a *copy* of that slice of `img`, and consequently any changes you made to `v` would not be reflected in `img`. The view ensures that `v` remains coupled to `img`.

> The image size is (1200, 1920, 3), but size of img[:, :, 2] is (1676348,).

For accuracy, I should point out that's not true. Using `img` from above:

```
julia> size(img[:,:,2])
(2, 2)
```

Comment: The syntax `img[mask, 2] .= 0` may be supported starting in Julia 1.6, see https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/38193.

Answer (score 4):

Edit:

The fast way to do it is:

```
@views @. img[:, :, 2] *= img[:, :, 2] != img[:, :, 3]
```

and here is a benchmark:

```
julia> img = rand(1:3, 10000, 10000, 3);

julia> @time @views @. img[:, :, 2] *= img[:, :, 2] != img[:, :, 3];
  0.111409 seconds (28 allocations: 1.219 KiB)
```

---

There are alternative ways to do what you want, but if we want to follow your implementation then do:

```
julia> img = rand(1:3, 4,4,3)
4×4×3 Array{Int64,3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 1  3  2  3
 1  1  1  3
 3  2  1  3
 2  2  3  1

[:, :, 2] =
 1  2  3  2
 2  2  1  1
 3  3  3  2
 1  3  2  1

[:, :, 3] =
 3  2  2  2
 3  2  2  1
 3  2  3  3
 2  2  1  2

julia> mask = img[:, :, 2] .== img[:, :, 3]
4×4 BitArray{2}:
 0  1  0  1
 0  1  0  1
 1  0  1  0
 0  0  0  0

julia> view(img,:, :, 2)[mask] .= 0;

julia> img
4×4×3 Array{Int64,3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 1  3  2  3
 1  1  1  3
 3  2  1  3
 2  2  3  1

[:, :, 2] =
 1  0  3  0
 2  0  1  0
 0  3  0  2
 1  3  2  1

[:, :, 3] =
 3  2  2  2
 3  2  2  1
 3  2  3  3
 2  2  1  2
```

(it is crucial to use `view` to get what you want, as otherwise `img[:, :, 2]` creates a copy)

Alternatively in Julia it is easy enough to write the same using the loop e.g.:

```
function applymask!(img)
    for i in axes(img, 1), j in axes(img, 2)
        img[i, j, 2] == img[i, j, 3] && (img[i, j, 2] = 0)
    end
end
```

(this is not the fastest possible implementation as it uses branching and does bounds checking, but it should be good enough in most cases)

And now you can write:

```
julia> img = rand(1:3, 4,4,3)
4×4×3 Array{Int64,3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 1  3  1  3
 3  3  1  2
 3  3  3  3
 2  1  3  1

[:, :, 2] =
 3  1  3  1
 3  3  3  3
 2  1  1  3
 1  2  3  3

[:, :, 3] =
 1  1  2  1
 2  1  3  2
 3  3  1  1
 1  2  1  3

julia> applymask!(img)

julia> img
4×4×3 Array{Int64,3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 1  3  1  3
 3  3  1  2
 3  3  3  3
 2  1  3  1

[:, :, 2] =
 3  0  3  0
 3  3  0  3
 2  1  0  3
 0  0  3  0

[:, :, 3] =
 1  1  2  1
 2  1  3  2
 3  3  1  1
 1  2  1  3
```

Comment: A apply this to (1200, 1920, 3) image and it takes about 3 seconds.
I want finish this process less than 1 seconds.
Do you know more faster methods?

Comment: Sorry Bogumil, I should have refreshed before posting, thanks for answering this.

Comment: @Koney, are you sure that wasn't compile time? It should be almost instantaneous.

Comment: @tholy - actually it is great to have you comment on this. I have added in my answer an edit that shows a more efficient way to do what is asked for.

Comment: @Kotaro - I have added a benchmark to my answer which for 70x larger matrix than yours runs in 0.1 second.